# xerces-c: Transcoding of Umlaute from iso8859-1 fails

Tags: c++

i try to migrate from xerces-c 2.7 to 3.1 on my linux system.
Due to legacy issues we work with iso8859-1.

Unfortunately all german umlaute are transformed to 0xfdfd and the data in my Dom are invalid when i use sth. like:

```
XMLCh* fUnicodeForm =XMLString::transcode("äöü");
```

will be transformed to 0xfdfd 0xfdfd 0xfdfd 0x0000.

The transcoding worked well with xerces-c 2.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, this is not officially supported. The problem is that the transcoding is assuming an internal code page, which apparently no longer matches ISO-8859-1.

`TranscodeFromStr` takes an explicit encoding.